# Getting NullPointerException when using OpenJPA on Tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, intellij-idea, openjpa

I am learning J2EE recently.
I use `IntelliJ`, and my web server is `Tomcat`. I want to add `OpenJPA` to my project, but I meet some problems.

I have two entities: `BooksEntity` and `SourcesEntity`.

When I called `createEntityManager()` in the `Servlet`, it gave me a `NullPointerException`.

It seems that I missed something, but I don't know why.

Here is the exception information:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    controller.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:28)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

This is my `TestServlet.java` file:

```
@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/books"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @PersistenceUnit (unitName = "booksPU")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Books.findAll");

        request.setAttribute("books", (List<BooksEntity>) query.getResultList());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

The exception was thrown in this line: `EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();`

This is my `context.xml` file:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="root" password="******" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FIRST_TEST"/>
</Context>
```

My `persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="booksPU">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>model.BooksEntity</class>
        <class>model.SourcesEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/FIRST_TEST"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="root"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="******"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

========2014.06.06========

My directory structure:

[image: My directory structure]

========2014.06.07========

[image: Package]

Comment: You should also so us how you've packaged your application.

Comment: @Rick I uploaded the image about my project directory structure. Do you mean this one?

Comment: I did not know a webapp run in Tomcat can use PersistenceUnit annotation injection without Spring or similar library, do you have any? I have created this tomcat+openjpa wrapper for my personal projects but its not using annotation injection, https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a typo in your code. The annotation should be `@PersistenceContext`, not `@PersistentUnit`. This is why `emf` remains `null`.

Comment: I think this is not a mistake. `@PersistenceUnit` is for `EntityManagerFactory`, and `@PersistenceContext` is for `EntityManager`. They are different.

Comment: Although I use `@PersistenceContext` and `EntityManager` directly, `EntityManager em` is still `null`.:(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you package your war file the persistence.xml is located in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` folder.

Comment: I uploaded a new image. Is it like that? I did it, but it still didn't work.